# It is all those or there are all those

Tags: past-tense, clauses

I am not sure if it is appropriate to use "it is/was" or “there is/was” in the following situation:

( I was trying to tell what I was surprised to see in my way to visit a friend to my sister)

*“Who would have thought after you turned into the street next to the graveyard, **it was** all those nice townhouses.”*

*“Who would have thought after you turned into the street next to the graveyard, **there were** all those nice townhouses.”*

Tenses:
In the same situation will it be appropriate to use past tense to describe what I saw or present tense since I am describing a true scenario.

*“Who would have thought after you **turn/turned** into the street next to the graveyard, it **is/was** all those nice townhouses.”*

*“Who would have thought after you turned into the street next to the graveyard, there **are/were** all those nice townhouses.”*

Comment: None of them sounds good to me. I would have ended with _that there would be all those nice townhouses_

Comment: As this is for language learners:  ( I was trying to tell what I was surprised to see **on** my way to visit a friend **of** my sister)

Comment: **There was/were** [something] is a natural way of saying that you saw it unexpectedly. However, if you were describing something _you_ saw on the way, you would say "after I turned into the street".